# How can I handle the millis() rollover?

Tags: programming, time, millis

I need to read a sensor every five minutes, but since my sketch also has
other tasks to do, I cannot just `delay()` between the readings. There
is the [Blink without
delay](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) tutorial
suggesting I code along these lines:

```c++
void loop()
{
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

    // Read the sensor when needed.
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
        readSensor();
    }

    // Do other stuff...
}
```

The problem is that `millis()` is going to roll over back to zero after
roughly 49.7 days. Since my sketch is intended to run for longer
than that, I need to make sure the rollover does not make my sketch
fail. I can easily detect the rollover condition
(`currentMillis < previousMillis`), but I am not sure what to do then.

Thus my question: what would be the proper/simplest way to handle the
`millis()` rollover?

Comment: Editorial note: This is not exactly a question of mine, rather a tutorial in a question/answer format. I have witnessed a lot of confusion on the Internet (including here) about this topic, and this site seems like the obvious place to search for an answer. This is why I am providing this tutorial here.

Comment: I would do `previousMillis += interval` instead of `previousMillis = currentMillis` if I wanted a certain frequency of results.

Comment: @Jasen: That's right! `previousMillis += interval` if you want constant frequency and are sure that your processing takes less than `interval`, but `previousMillis = currentMillis` for guaranteeing a minimum delay of `interval`.

Comment: We really need a FAQ for things like this.

Comment: One of the "tricks" I use is to lighten the load on the arduino by using the smallest int that contains the interval. For instance, for max 1 minute intervals, I write `uint16_t previousMillis; const uint16_t interval = 45000; ... uint16_t currentMillis = (uint16_t) millis(); if ((currentMillis - previousMillis) >= interval) ...`

Comment: @frarugi87: I sometimes do the same. Note however that, if that type turns out to be smaller than `int` (`uint8_t`, but also `uint16_t` on ARM), you have to cast the result of the subtraction to the appropriate type. Otherwise, because of [integer promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions), you end up with the wrong type. BTW, the cast you did write (casting `millis()`) is redundant.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I never totally understood the automatic promotions, so forgive me if this question seems stupid, but.. if all the elements (currentMillis, previousMillis, interval) are uint16_t, will it "promote" the subtraction to let's say int32_t (and so break what I wanted to do)? As for the cast, it's just out of habit (implicit casts raise MISRA warnings, so I tend to avoid implicit casts)

Comment: @frarugi87: For each binary operation, if both arguments are smaller than a plain `int`, then they are both implicitly promoted to `int`. Otherwise the smaller is converted to the type of the larger, with a preference to the unsigned types (I am oversimplifying a bit, but it's the main idea).

Comment: @EdgarBonet thanks for the explanation; I need to keep this in mind when doing <250ms cycles on 8-bit processors to save memory... (8-bit operations on 16-bit processors, as well as 8/16-bit operations on 32-bit processors, do not save memory nor flash)

Comment: I wish some answer included opinion on restarting your device, or solution where you manually detect overflow (`millis() < 1000`) and reset variables timestamps that use `nextUpdateMillis` as `if (currentMillis <= nextUpdateMillis) { }`.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Short answer: do not try to “handle” the millis rollover, write
rollover-safe code instead. Your example code from the tutorial is fine.
If you try to detect the rollover in order to implement corrective
measures, chances are you are doing something wrong. Most Arduino
programs only have to manage events that span relatively short
durations, like debouncing a button for 50 ms, or turning a heater
on for 12 hours... Then, and even if the program is meant to run
for years at a time, the millis rollover should not be a concern.

The correct way to manage (or rather, avoid having to manage) the
rollover problem is to think of the `unsigned long` number returned by
`millis()` in terms of [modular
arithmetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). For the
mathematically inclined, some familiarity with this concept is very
useful when programming. You can see the math in action in Nick Gammon's
article [millis() overflow ... a bad
thing?](https://www.gammon.com.au/millis). For the problem at hand,
what's important to know is that in modular arithmetics the numbers
“wrap around” when reaching a certain value – the modulus – so that
1 − modulus is not a negative number but 1 (think of a
12 hour clock where the modulus is 12: here 1 − 12 = 1).

For those who do not want to
go through the computational details, I offer here an alternative
(hopefully simpler) way of thinking about it. It is based on the simple
distinction between *instants* and *durations*. As long as your tests
only involve comparing durations, you should be fine.

**Note on micros()**: Everything said here about `millis()` applies
equally to `micros()`, except for the fact that `micros()` rolls over
every 71.6 minutes, and the `setMillis()` function provided below
does not affect `micros()`.

### Instants, timestamps and durations

When dealing with time, we have to make the distinction between at least
two different concepts: *instants* and *durations*. An instant is a
point on the time axis. A duration is the length of a time interval,
i.e. the distance in time between the instants that define the start and
the end of the interval. The distinction between these concepts is not
always very sharp in everyday language. For example, if I say “*I will
be back in five minutes*”, then “*five minutes*” is the estimated
*duration* of my absence, whereas “*in five minutes*” is the *instant*
of my predicted coming back. Keeping the distinction in mind is
important, because it is the simplest way to entirely avoid the rollover
problem.

The return value of `millis()` could be interpreted as a duration: the
time elapsed from the start of the program until now. This
interpretation, however, breaks down as soon as millis overflows. It is
generally far more useful to think of `millis()` as returning a
*timestamp*, i.e. a “label” identifying a particular instant. It could
be argued that this interpretation suffers from these labels being
ambiguous, as they are reused every 49.7 days. This is, however,
seldom a problem: in most embedded applications, anything that happened
49.7 days ago is ancient history we do not care about. Thus,
recycling the old labels should not be an issue.

### Do not compare timestamps

Trying to find out which among two timestamps is greater than the other
does not make sense. Example:

```c
unsigned long t1 = millis();
delay(3000);
unsigned long t2 = millis();
if (t2 > t1) { ... }
```

Naively, one would expect the condition of the `if ()` to be always
true. But it will actually be false if millis overflows during
`delay(3000)`. Thinking of t1 and t2 as recyclable labels is the
simplest way to avoid the error: the label t1 has clearly been assigned
to an instant prior to t2, but in 49.7 days it will be reassigned
to a future instant. Thus, t1 happens both *before* and *after* t2. This
should make clear that the expression `t2 > t1` makes no sense.

But, if these are mere labels, the obvious question is: how can we do
any useful time calculations with them? The answer is: by restricting
ourselves to the only two calculations that make sense for timestamps:

1. `later_timestamp - earlier_timestamp` yields a duration, namely the
   amount of time elapsed between the earlier instant and the later
   instant. This is the most useful arithmetic operation involving
   timestamps.
2. `timestamp ± duration` yields a timestamp which is some time after
   (if using +) or before (if −) the initial timestamp. Not as useful as
   it sounds, since the resulting timestamp can be used in only two
   kinds of calculations...

Thanks to modular arithmetics, both of these are guaranteed to work fine
across the millis rollover, at least as long as the delays involved are
shorter than 49.7 days.

### Comparing durations is fine

A duration is just the amount of milliseconds elapsed during some time
interval. As long as we do not need to handle durations longer than
49.7 days, any operation that physically makes sense should also
make sense computationally. We can, for example, multiply a duration by
a frequency to get a number of periods. Or we can compare two durations
to know which one is longer. For example, here are two alternative
implementations of `delay()`. First, the buggy one:

```c
void myDelay(unsigned long ms) {          // ms: duration
    unsigned long start = millis();       // start: timestamp
    unsigned long finished = start + ms;  // finished: timestamp
    for (;;) {
        unsigned long now = millis();     // now: timestamp
        if (now >= finished)              // comparing timestamps: BUG!
            return;
    }
}
```

And here is the correct one:

```c
void myDelay(unsigned long ms) {              // ms: duration
    unsigned long start = millis();           // start: timestamp
    for (;;) {
        unsigned long now = millis();         // now: timestamp
        unsigned long elapsed = now - start;  // elapsed: duration
        if (elapsed >= ms)                    // comparing durations: OK
            return;
    }
}
```

Most C programmers would write the above loops in a terser form, like

```c
while (millis() < start + ms) ;  // BUGGY version
```

and

```c
while (millis() - start < ms) ;  // CORRECT version
```

Although they look deceptively similar, the timestamp/duration
distinction should make clear which one is buggy and which one is
correct.

### What if I really need to compare timestamps?

Better try to avoid the situation. If it is unavoidable, there is still
hope if it is known that the respective instants are close enough:
closer than 24.85 days. Yes, our maximum manageable delay of
49.7 days just got cut in half.

The obvious solution is to convert our timestamp comparison problem into
a duration comparison problem. Say we need to know whether instant t1 is
before or after t2. We choose some reference instant in their common
past, and compare the durations from this reference until both t1 and
t2. The reference instant is obtained by subtracting a long enough
duration from either t1 or t2:

```c
unsigned long reference_instant = t2 - LONG_ENOUGH_DURATION;
unsigned long from_reference_until_t1 = t1 - reference_instant;
unsigned long from_reference_until_t2 = t2 - reference_instant;
if (from_reference_until_t1 < from_reference_until_t2)
    // t1 is before t2
```

This can be simplified as:

```c
if (t1 - t2 + LONG_ENOUGH_DURATION < LONG_ENOUGH_DURATION)
    // t1 is before t2
```

It is tempting to simplify further into `if (t1 - t2 < 0)`. Obviously,
this does not work, because `t1 - t2`, being computed as an unsigned
number, cannot be negative. This, however, although not portable, does
work:

```c
if ((signed long)(t1 - t2) < 0)  // works with gcc
    // t1 is before t2
```

The keyword `signed` above is redundant (a plain `long` is always
signed), but it helps make the intent clear. Converting to a signed long
is equivalent to setting `LONG_ENOUGH_DURATION` equal to
24.85 days. The trick is not portable because, according to the C
standard, the result is *implementation defined*. But since the gcc
compiler [promises to do the right
thing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html),
it works reliably on Arduino. If we wish to avoid implementation defined
behavior, the above signed comparison is mathematically equivalent to
this:

```c
#include <limits.h>

if (t1 - t2 > LONG_MAX)  // too big to be believed
    // t1 is before t2
```

with the only problem that the comparison looks backwards. It is also
equivalent, as long as longs are 32-bits, to this single-bit test:

```c
if ((t1 - t2) & 0x80000000)  // test the "sign" bit
    // t1 is before t2
```

The last three tests are actually compiled by gcc into the exact same
machine code.

### How do I test my sketch against the millis rollover

If you follow the precepts above, you should be all good. If you
nevertheless want to test, add this function to your sketch:

```c
#include <util/atomic.h>

void setMillis(unsigned long ms)
{
    extern unsigned long timer0_millis;
    ATOMIC_BLOCK (ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) {
        timer0_millis = ms;
    }
}
```

and you can now time-travel your program by calling
`setMillis(destination)`. If you want it to go through the millis
overflow over and over again, like Phil Connors reliving Groundhog Day,
you can put this inside `loop()`:

```c
// 6-second time loop starting at rollover - 3 seconds
if (millis() - (-3000) >= 6000)
    setMillis(-3000);
```

The negative timestamp above (-3000) is implicitly converted by the
compiler to an unsigned long corresponding to 3000 milliseconds before
the rollover (it is converted to 4294964296).

### What if I really need to track very long durations?

If you need to turn a relay on and turn it off three months later, then
you really need to track the millis overflows. There are many ways to do
so. The most straightforward solution may be to simply extend `millis()`
to 64 bits:

```c
uint64_t millis64() {
    static uint32_t low32, high32;
    uint32_t new_low32 = millis();
    if (new_low32 < low32) high32++;
    low32 = new_low32;
    return (uint64_t) high32 << 32 | low32;
}
```

This is essentially counting the rollover events, and using this count
as the 32 most significant bits of a 64 bit millisecond count.
For this counting to work properly, the function needs to be called at
least once every 49.7 days. However, if it is only called once per 49.7 days, for some cases it is possible that the check `(new_low32 < low32)` fails and the code misses a count of `high32`. Using millis() to decide when to make the only call to this code in a single "wrap" of millis (a specific 49.7 day window) could be very hazardous, depending on how the time frames line up. For safety, if using millis() to determine when to make the only calls to millis64(), there should be at least two calls in every 49.7 day window.

Keep in mind, though, that 64 bit arithmetic is expensive on the
Arduino. It may be worth to reduce the time resolution in order to stay
at 32 bits.

Comment: So, you are saying that the code written in the question will actually work correctly?

Comment: @Jasen: Exactly! I've seem more than once people trying to “fix” the problem that did not exist in the first place.

Comment: I'm glad I found this. I've had this question before.

Comment: One of the best and most useful answers on StackExchange! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: This is such an amazing answer to the question. I come back to this answer basically once a year because I am paranoid of messing rollovers.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, except that it doesn't appear possible to "see" timer0_millis from a sketch anymore; you can declare it extern but the linker does not see it. wiring.c does not declare timer0_millis as static so I'm not sure what exactly they're doing, but the answer may need an update.

Comment: @AndrewKohlsmith: I just tested `setMillis()` on an Uno, with the Arduino IDE 1.8.10. It works as expected.

Comment: +1. Such an in depth answer that I think my millis() rolled over reading it.

Comment: For the use-case of scheduling future events, I really like the compare timestamp forms, rather than forcing them into the common pattern of comparing always non-negative durations since past events.  // You tested the three timestamp-comparison codes on GCC, do you know of compilers that do the the wrong thing/behave differently with the different codes?  // Would `if ((t1 - t2) & 0x80000000)  // test the "sign" bit` actually be portable on machines with wider unsigned long sizes?

Comment: @DaveX: Re: “_do you know of compilers that do the the wrong thing [when converting an unsigned integer to signed]?_”: I don't, and I don't think such a compiler would be easy to come by. Reducing an n-bit integer modulo 2^n is the only option that makes sense with two's complement, and other signed integer representations are practically gone. Note that, since C++20, this behavior is mandatory. Even though Arduino may not be using C++20, I take this as a sign that most current C++ implementations already do this.

Comment: @DaveX: Re: “_Would `if ((t1 - t2) & 0x80000000)` [...] be portable on machines with wider unsigned long sizes_”: That wouldn't test the sign bit (which is `0x8000000000000000` on a 64-bit long), but it would still work if `t1` and `t2` are less than 2^31 ms apart.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! If I am only interested in very short durations (say only debouncing switches), it seems like there's no reason to use the "unsigned long" type. I could go with a byte, as long as I don't intend to have durations longer than 255 ms,  right? (I understand that `millis()` returns an "unsigned long" but I could write my own function that returns a byte in this case)

Comment: @RobD: In principle, yes. You have, however, to be aware of the [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/usual_arithmetic_conversions) performed by C++. If `started` and `now` are bytes (type `uint8_t`), then `now-started` is a (potentially negative) `int`. Using `unsigned int` would be safer (no integral promotion) as long as you do not write an expression like `millis()-started`, which would implicitly convert `started` to `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 36):

**TL;DR** Short version:

An `unsigned long` is 0 to 4,294,967,295 (2^32 - 1).

So lets say `previousMillis` is 4,294,967,290 (5 ms before rollover), and `currentMillis` is 10 (10ms after rollover). Then `currentMillis - previousMillis` is actual 16 (not -4,294,967,280) since the result will be calculated as an **unsigned** long (which can't be negative, so itself will roll around). You can check this simply by:

`Serial.println( ( unsigned long ) ( 10 - 4294967290 ) ); // 16`

So the above code will work perfectly fine. The trick is to always calculate the time difference, and not compare the two time values.

Comment: How about a **15ms** before rollover and a **10ms** after rollover (ie 49.7 days *after*). **15 > 10**, but the **15ms** stamp is nearly a month and a half old. *15-10 > 0 and 10-15 > 0* `unsigned` logic, so that is no use here!

Comment: @prakharsingh95 10ms-15ms will become ~49.7 days - 5ms, which is the correct difference. The math works until `millis()` rolls over twice, but that is very unlikely to occur to the code in question.

Comment: Let me rephrase. Suppose you have two timestamps 200ms and 10ms. How do you tell which is(are) rolled over?

Comment: @prakharsingh95 The one stored in `previousMillis` has to have been measured before `currentMillis`, so if `currentMillis` is smaller than `previousMillis` a rollover occurred. The math happens to work out that unless two rollovers have occurred, you don't even need to think about it.

Comment: Ah, ok. if you do `t2-t1`, and if you can guarantee `t1` is measured before `t2` then it's equivalent to **signed** `(t2-t1)% 4,294,967,295`, hence the auto wraparound. Nice!. But what if there are two rollovers, or `interval` is >  4,294,967,295?

Comment: Intervals larger that 49 days will be a bit more difficult, but in most applications not very useful, as the arduino crystal is not that accurate. Over 49 this inaccuracy could result in hours of error. Multiple rollovers can't occur since previousMillis is change when the interval has passed. PS the formula would actually be `(t2-t1+4,294,967,295) % 4,294,967,295` since modulo will also give negative values (e.g. `-3%2==-1`)

Comment: does one need to cast the calculation result to unsigned long? Or will this be automatic if the calculation is executed with two variables already declared as unsigned long?

Comment: The accepted answer is very good but didn't explain this part.

Answer (score 6):

I loved this question, and the great answers it generated. First a quick comment on a previous answer (I know, I know, but I don't have the rep to comment yet. :-).

Edgar Bonet's answer was amazing. I've been coding for 35 years, and I learned something new today. Thank you. That said, I believe the code for *"What if I really need to track very long durations?"* breaks unless you call millis64() at least once per rollover period. Really nitpicky, and unlikely to be an issue in a real-world implementation, but there you go.

Now, if you really did want timestamps covering any sane time range (64-bits of milliseconds is about half a billion years by my reckoning), it looks simple to extend the existing millis() implementation to 64 bits.

These changes to attinycore/wiring.c (I'm working with the ATTiny85) seem to work (I'm assuming the code for other AVRs is very similar). See the lines with the //BFB comments, and the new millis64() function. Clearly it's going to be both bigger (98 bytes of code, 4 bytes of data) and slower, and as Edgar pointed out, you almost certainly can accomplish your goals with just a better understanding of unsigned integer math, but it was an interesting exercise.

```
volatile unsigned long long timer0_millis = 0;      // BFB: need 64-bit resolution

#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny24__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny44__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny84__)
ISR(TIM0_OVF_vect)
#else
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
#endif
{
    // copy these to local variables so they can be stored in registers
    // (volatile variables must be read from memory on every access)
    unsigned long long m = timer0_millis;       // BFB: need 64-bit resolution
    unsigned char f = timer0_fract;

    m += MILLIS_INC;
    f += FRACT_INC;
    if (f >= FRACT_MAX) {
        f -= FRACT_MAX;
        m += 1;
    }

    timer0_fract = f;
    timer0_millis = m;
    timer0_overflow_count++;
}

// BFB: 64-bit version
unsigned long long millis64()
{
    unsigned long long m;
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;

    // disable interrupts while we read timer0_millis or we might get an
    // inconsistent value (e.g. in the middle of a write to timer0_millis)
    cli();
    m = timer0_millis;
    SREG = oldSREG;

    return m;
}
```

Comment: You are right, my `millis64()` only works if it is called more frequently than the rollover period. I edited my answer to point out this limitation. Your version does not have this issue, but it carries another drawback: it does 64-bit arithmetics _in interrupt context_, which occasionally increases the latency in responding to other interrupts.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `millis()` in a class!

Logic:

1. Use id's instead of `millis()` directly.
2. Compare reversals using id's. This is clean and rollover independent.
3. For specific applications, to calculate exact difference between two id's, keep track of reversals and stamps. Calculate the difference.

Keeping track of reversals:

1. Update a local stamp periodically faster than `millis()`. This will help you find out if `millis()` has overflown.
2. The period of the timer determines accuracy

```c++
class Timer {

public:
    static long last_stamp;
    static long *stamps;
    static int *reversals;
    static int count;
    static int reversal_count;

    static void setup_timer() {
        // Setup Timer2 overflow to fire every 8ms (125Hz)
        //   period [sec] = (1 / f_clock [sec]) * prescale * (255-count)
        //                  (1/16000000)  * 1024 * (255-130) = .008 sec


        TCCR2B = 0x00;        // Disable Timer2 while we set it up

        TCNT2  = 130;         // Reset Timer Count  (255-130) = execute ev 125-th T/C clock
        TIFR2  = 0x00;        // Timer2 INT Flag Reg: Clear Timer Overflow Flag
        TIMSK2 = 0x01;        // Timer2 INT Reg: Timer2 Overflow Interrupt Enable
        TCCR2A = 0x00;        // Timer2 Control Reg A: Wave Gen Mode normal
        TCCR2B = 0x07;        // Timer2 Control Reg B: Timer Prescaler set to 1024

        count = 0;
        stamps = new long[50];
        reversals = new int [10];
        reversal_count =0;
    }

    static long get_stamp () {
        stamps[count++] = millis();
        return count-1;
    }

    static bool compare_stamps_by_id(int s1, int s2) {
        return s1 > s2;
    }

    static long long get_stamp_difference(int s1, int s2) {
        int no_of_reversals = 0;
        for(int j=0; j < reversal_count; j++)
        if(reversals[j] < s2 && reversals[j] > s1)
            no_of_reversals++;
        return stamps[s2]-stamps[s1] + 49.7 * 86400 * 1000;       
    }

};

long Timer::last_stamp;
long *Timer::stamps;
int *Timer::reversals;
int Timer::count;
int Timer::reversal_count;

ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect) {

    long stamp = millis();
    if(stamp < Timer::last_stamp) // reversal
        Timer::reversals[Timer::reversal_count++] = Timer::count;
    else 
        ; // no reversal
    Timer::last_stamp = stamp;    
    TCNT2 = 130;     // reset timer ct to 130 out of 255
    TIFR2 = 0x00;    // timer2 int flag reg: clear timer overflow flag
};

// Usage

void setup () {
    Timer::setup_timer();

    long s1 = Timer::get_stamp();
    delay(3000);
    long s2 = Timer::get_stamp();

    Timer::compare_stamps_by_id(s1, s2); // true

    Timer::get_stamp_difference(s1, s2); // return true difference, taking into account reversals
}
```

[Timer credits](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/how-do-i-create-a-timer-interrupt-with-arduino).

Comment: I edited the code to remove the maaaaany errors that prevented it to compile. This stuff will cost you about 232 bytes of RAM and two PWM channels. It will also start to corrupt the memory after you `get_stamp()` 51 times. Comparing delays instead of timestamps will certainly be more efficient.

Comment: Isn't that full static class effectively like namespace?