# Unable to create a desired periodic signal with Arduino Mega 2560 and DAC0808

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide, electronics

I wrote the code to produce the periodic signal by using arduino and DAC0808 where i turned on and off the respectively pins of PORTA by using a logic in iterative manner and created the periodic signal. But even without using delay logic, i couldn't get signal time period as comparable to 50 Hz voltage signal. And what i seek to get is to decrease the time period of generated signal. Pls note, blue signal is reference signal of 50Hz frequency.

```
float increment = 3.14159 / 500;
float initial = 0;
float value = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  DDRA  = B11111111;
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  PORTA = B00000000;
  while (1)
  {
    initial = initial + increment;
    value = sin(initial)  * 255;
    PORTA = abs(value);
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Your goal is to optimize the code to run faster? Start by using a look-up table instead of sin() and minimize float arithmetics. Are you sure your increment is correct?

Comment: You should make more clear what you expect to get and what you get instead.

Comment: Please edit question and indicate the timebase (seconds per division).  Also, if wiring diagram as shown is different than what you actually have, say so.  (The diagram apparently wires the bits backwards, LSB to MSB and vice versa.)

Comment: jwpat7 sir, blue signal is output signal of 50hz. So, time period per box is around 25 milli second.sorry for the inconvenience as am i operating from mobile.

Comment: As Vicente said, floating point math, especially transcendental functions, can be time-consuming. Instead of calculating the sine inside every repetition, you should build up a lookup table in your setup() function, then get the values from this table inside loop(). In order to minimise the size of the lookup table, note that you only need to calculate the sines of values from 0 to pi/2. If you still can not get your arduino to produce a 50Hz signal after that, consider decreasing the 'resolution' - that is, increasing the value of 'increment' from pi/500 to, say, pi/100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned before, in comments and in jwpat7's answer, your
main problem here is the time taken to compute the sines. I already
provided a link to a [faster fixed-point implementation of
`sin()`](https://www.logre.eu/wiki/Trigonom%C3%A9trie_en_virgule_fixe) but, since you have an Mega2560 with loads of RAM, I
would go to the simpler look-up table method. I would not even bother
optimizing the size of the table.

For controlling the timing, you can use the canonical method described
in the [Blink Without Delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) Arduino tutorial, with one twist: times
should be measures with `micros()` instead of `millis()`. Here is a
first version of the program:

```c++
const float FREQUENCY = 50;            // hertz
const float PERIOD = 1e6 / FREQUENCY;  // microseconds
const size_t TABLE_SIZE = 512;
const uint16_t SAMPLE_TIME = PERIOD/TABLE_SIZE + 0.5;
uint8_t wavetable[TABLE_SIZE];

void setup()
{
    // Prepare the wavetable.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
        wavetable[i] = 255 * abs(sin(M_PI * i / TABLE_SIZE));
    }

    // Set port A as output.
    DDRA = 0xff;
}

void loop()
{
    uint16_t now = micros();
    static uint16_t last_sample;
    static size_t phase;

    if (now - last_sample > SAMPLE_TIME) {
        last_sample += SAMPLE_TIME;
        PORTA = wavetable[phase];
        phase = (phase + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;
    }
}
```

A few things worth noting:

1. The float constants `FREQUENCY` and `PERIOD` are used only at compile
   time.
2. The table size is a power of two because wrapping a table index
   modulo a power of two is way faster than modulo, say, 500: the
   compiler optimizes the modulo into a bitwise AND.
3. The `+ 0.5` in the expression of `SAMPLE_TIME` is intended to ensure
   that the result is rounded to the *nearest* integer. In this instance
   it happens to be useless because rounding down would give the same
   result.
4. The `micros()` function returns a 32-bit integer, but in this
   application it is sufficient and faster to track only the 16 least
   significant bits, hence the `uint16_t` timing variables. And no,
   [these variables overflowing is not a problem](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12587).

This should give you, in theory, a frequency of 50.08 Hz, i.e.
0.16% too fast. The discrepancy is due to `SAMPLE_TIME`, which should be
39.0625 µs, being rounded to 39 µs. You could fix this by
counting time with a higher resolution, but given the poor accuracy of
the ceramic resonator clocking the Arduino, this is probably not worth
the trouble.

A potentially worse problem is the large jitter you have with this
approach, on the order of 10 µs. This is due both to the time taken
to run through the loop and the occasional timer interrupt taking some
extra time. You can get rid of this jitter by using a timer interrupt
instead of `micros()`. Here is a second version of the program that uses
this approach:

```c++
#include <avr/sleep.h>

const float FREQUENCY = 50;              // hertz
const float PERIOD = F_CPU / FREQUENCY;  // CPU cycles
const size_t TABLE_SIZE = 512;
const uint16_t SAMPLE_TIME = PERIOD/TABLE_SIZE + 0.5;
uint8_t wavetable[TABLE_SIZE];

int main()
{
    // Prepare the wavetable.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
        wavetable[i] = 255 * abs(sin(M_PI * i / TABLE_SIZE));
    }

    // Set port A as output.
    DDRA = 0xff;

    // Configure Timer 1.
    OCR1A = SAMPLE_TIME - 1;  // set the period
    TIMSK1 = _BV(OCIE1A);     // enable TIMER1_COMPA interrupt
    TCCR1B = _BV(WGM12)       // CTC mode with TOP = OCR1A
           | _BV(CS10);       // clock at F_CPU / 1

    // Sleep while waiting for interrupts.
    sei();
    sleep_enable();
    for (;;) sleep_cpu();
}

// Service routine for the Timer 1 interrupt.
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
    static size_t phase;

    PORTA = wavetable[phase];
    phase = (phase + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;
}
```

Again, a few notes:

1. The `SAMPLE_TIME` is now computed in CPU cycles and, since it is an
   integer number of cycles (namely 625), there should in principle be
   no frequency discrepancy.
2. For counting 625 cycles we need a 16-bit timer clocked at the full
   CPU speed (prescaler = 1). We are using Timer 1 here. See the
   [datasheet of the ATmega2560](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf), chapter 17, for details on
   using the timer.
3. Sleeping between interrupts is needed in order to obtain
   cycle-accurate timings. If we had simply an infinite loop, there
   could be a few CPU cycles of jitter, which may not be a big deal.
4. Writing `main()` instead of `setup()` and `loop()` is a way to skip
   the initialization normally done by the Arduino core library. In this
   application that initialization is better avoided, because it creates
   an extra jitter-inducing interrupt and it messes with Timer 1 in a
   way that we would need to undo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting your phrase “even without using delay logic, i couldn't get signal time period as comparable to 50 Hz” as meaning that the code shown runs Too Slow.  At 1000 samples per cycle and 50 Hz on an 8-bit 16-MHz processor, you only have 320 clocks to compute a `sin()`, which probably is not enough to compute a 32-bit floating `sin()`.

To speed it up, you can either issue fewer samples per cycle or make the loop go faster.

For the “fewer samples per cycle” approach, you would make `increment` bigger; for example, instead of 3.14159/500, or 1000 samples per cycle, perhaps an interval of 2π/500, or 500 samples per cycle.

For the “make the loop go faster” approach, you could use a lookup table or fixed-point integer arithmetic or both.  Note, the lookup table only needs to cover 90° (or π/2 radians); index in reverse for quadrants 2 and 4, and negate values for quadrants 3 and 4.

Note, after you speed up the code, you will need to set up a time base for issuing samples.  This could use a clock-based interrupt routine that gets and issues the next array value, or that sets a flag so your main loop can get and issue a value.  Or you could spin until `micros()` exceeds a deadline, at which time you (1) issue a value, (2) set the next deadline, and (3) compute the next value.

Comment: 320 clock cycles is indeed not enough for `sin()`: I have timed it at 1725.1 cycles average. I've also written a [fixed-point `sin()` that takes 110.25 cycles](https://www.logre.eu/wiki/Trigonom%C3%A9trie_en_virgule_fixe) (page in French, but code documented in English). It's 16 bits, with a maximum error of 9.53e-5, so somewhat overkill for this 8-bit application. But a simpler alternative polynomial is given in the text.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, thanks for mentioning that –  it provides a viable alternative to table lookup methods.