# Is there a way to set an interrupt to go off after a certain period of time?

Tags: arduino-mega, sleep

I'm trying to save power by putting my device to sleep once it has run through the code once and turn it back on every 33 milliseconds. So basically, if the code finishes executing in 20 milliseconds the device can go to sleep for the remaining 13 milliseconds and it will be turned on by the interupt which is set to go off every 33 milliseocnds.

According to the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt) an interrupt is based on a change to the pin state, but I'm sure there must be a way to base it on time. If there isn't then is there a way to set the total time that a device sleeps? The sleep function seemed to just turn the device off, but can it be given a parameter to just turn off for a certain amount of time?

Comment: See for example [this answer](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/25280) for an example of setting a timer to periodically wake-up the Arduino Mega.

Comment: I saw the sleep function, but where are they setting the actual interrupt?

Comment: The line `TIMSK1 = _BV(OCIE1A);  // enable TIMER1_COMPA interrupt`, as the comment says, enables the interrupt.

Comment: Follow up question, is this code Arduino? I see a main method but no setup() or loop().

Comment: It's plain avr-libc, but it works under the Arduino environment.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve your purpose seems to be to configure a
timer to fire every 33 ms, and use this interrupt to wake up the
MCU. For this, you first have to choose what timer to use. On the Mega, I
would rather use the 16-bit timer, but the ATtiny85 only has 8-bit
timers. Next you have to choose a prescaler value (clock frequency
division) among those available for that timer. The prescaler should be
large enough to avoid overflowing your timer, but smaller prescaler
values give better time resolution.

Then you configure the timer to run in “CTC mode” (clear timer on
compare match). In this mode, it counts from zero to the value that you
programmed in the `OCRxA` register (where `x` is the number identifying
the timer), and then goes back to zero. This way you can get an
interrupt every `OCRxA + 1` timer cycles.

In the example code below, you have to replace `x` with the appropriate
timer number, and check the datasheet for the bits to set in the control
registers `TCCR*`:

```c++
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

// Interrupt period, in prescaled clock cycles.
const uint16_t PERIOD = ...;  // or uint8_t for an 8-bit timer.

// The timer interrupt is used ONLY to wake the CPU, so there is no job
// to be done inside the interrupt service routine.
EMPTY_INTERRUPT(TIMERx_COMPA_vect);

void setup()
{
    // Disable Timer 0 interrupts.
    // Warning: this will prevent the Arduino from keeping time.
    TIMSK0 = 0;

    // Configure Timer x.
    TCCRxA = 0;            // undo the timer config done...
    TCCRxB = 0;            // ...by the Arduino core library
    TCNTx = 0;             // reset the timer
    OCRxA = PERIOD - 1;    // set the period
    TIMSKx = _BV(OCIExA);  // enable TIMERx_COMPA interrupt
    TCCRxA = ...;          // set the counting mode to CTC...
    TCCRxB = ...;          // ...and set the prescaler
}

void loop()
{
    // Sleep while waiting for the timer interrupt.
    sleep_mode();

    // Now that we have been waken up...
    do_the_job();
}
```

**Edit**: As noticed by Gerben, the Arduino core library configures
Timer 0 to send periodic interrupts (one every 1024 µs), which
are used for timekeeping (`millis()`, `delay()` and co.). This
interrupts will wake up the MCU and prevent it from sleeping as long as
you want. The simplest solution, which is implemented in the code above,
is to disable the Timer 0 interrupts. The drawback is that the
Arduino timekeeping functions will not work anymore.

If you need those timekeeping functions, then the proper solution is the
one sketched by Gerben in his comment: set a boolean in the interrupt
that can be checked in the main loop. Here is the naive implementation
of this idea: `EMPTY_INTERRUPT(TIMERx_COMPA_vect);` is replaced by

```c++
volatile bool time_elapsed;

ISR(TIMERx_COMPA_vect)
{
    time_elapsed = true;
}
```

Then, in the main loop you sleep repeatedly until the ISR sets the flag:

```c++
void loop()
{
    // Warning: race condition here!
    while (!time_elapsed)
        sleep_mode();
    time_elapsed = false;

    // Now that we have been waken up...
    do_the_job();
}
```

As stated in the comment, this naive implementation suffers from what is
known as a *race condition*. The problem is in the following scenario:

1. The main loop reads the value of `time_elapsed` and it turns out to
   be false
2. At this point the interrupt fires and the ISR sets that boolean to
   `true`
3. Returning from the ISR, the main loop does not test the flag again
   (since it just did it) and goes straight to `sleep_mode();`.

At this point the MCU ends up sleeping although it should be performing
the job which is due now.

This race condition may not a be a big deal to you: The MCU will be
eventually woken up by the Timer 0 interrupt no more than 1024 µs
later. In some cases it *is* an issue, but fortunately there is a proper
solution. It is described in the [page about sleeping of the avr-libc
documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__sleep.html). It relies on the fact that when interrupts are
disabled, then enabled again with `sei()`, the machine instruction right
after the `sei()` is guaranteed to be executed before any interrupt is
serviced. Then the proper way to test the flag and sleep is:

```c++
void loop()
{
    while (!time_elapsed) {
        cli();
        if (!time_elapsed) {
            sleep_enable();
            sei();          // interrupts enabled
            sleep_cpu();    // this will be executed before any ISR
            sleep_disable();
        }
        sei();
    }
    time_elapsed = false;

    // Now that we have been waken up...
    do_the_job();
}
```

With this version, if the interrupt fires right after the test
`if (!time_elapsed)`, it will be serviced *after* `sleep_cpu()`, which
will have the effect of waking the MCU right away.

Comment: Wow that helps a lot, but why do you subtract 1 from `PERIOD`? That other example did that too. Also, `PERIOD` is supposed to be the duration between interrupts, correct? So for my project I'd set it equal to the number of clock cycles that will equal 33 milliseconds. Right?

Comment: The counter counts from 0 to `OCRxA` **inclusive**, so the period is `OCRxA+1`. The period is in **prescaled** clock cycles, see the prescaler setting.

Comment: Timer0 (used for millis and delay) will also wake up the device. You probably need to set Boolean inside the interrupt, so the main loop can check if it needs to go back to sleep or not

Comment: Thanks @Gerben for noticing. You are absolutely right. I've amended the answer to account for this issue.

Comment: Nice solution for the race condition.

Answer (score 0):

There are many many kinds of interrupt. External interrupts (of the kind you use with `attachInterrupt()`) are but one.

Almost every internal peripheral in the AVR chip can generate an interrupt (or multiple interrupts in some cases). One of the most useful is the *timer interrupt* which is triggered by one of the timers when its timer has overflowed.

I am not familiar with the AVR's sleep mechanisms, but I would assume a timer interrupt can wake it from sleep - assuming the timer can run while sleeping.

You should check the documentation for the chip on your Arduino rather than relying on the (somewhat scant and basic, and often misleading) documentation on the Arduino website when it comes to doing anything low-level like this.

Comment: You are right: the timer interrupt can wake up the MCU, but only if it's sleeping in the so called “IDLE” mode... which is the default sleep mode anyway.

Comment: Does the setting of a timer interrupt vary from microcontroller to microcontroller? I'm trying to write this code on the Arduino Mega first and then port it to an ATtiny.

Comment: Yes. You should read the documentation for both your target microcontrollers and program accordingly - probably with copious usage of #ifdef ... #endif

Comment: @AngelLockhart: It's often not _that_ different. You could probably use the same code for the 16-bit timers of the ATmega2560 and the ATtiny84A. What ATtiny are you targeting? At what clock frequency?

Comment: The principle of operation will be almost the same between them. Numbers will change though (calculations for time vs clock frequency), and register names may change (depending on number of timers available, etc). In general, though, there will be a lot of copy-and-paste of logic blocks like these when it comes to designing chips in the same broad family.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I'm using the ATtiny85, also can you explain why the number would change? My plan was to calculate the time the program ran with `millis()` and then subtract that from 33 milliseconds. Will that not work?

Comment: Timers operate on clock ticks. You need to calculate how many clock ticks make up the time you need it to run for, and of course that changes depending on the speed the clock is running at.