# Use interrupts with analog pins in arduino or another possible solution?

Tags: lcd, potentiometer

I have a very simple circuit, but my program is some what complicated.

Here is the circuit diagram:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
/*
  01 - GND -------- GND
  02 - +5V -------- 5V
  03 - V0  -------- Potentiometer Middle
  04 - Reset ------ 9
  05 - Read/Write - GND
  06 - Enable ----- 8
  07 - Data0 ------ NC
  08 - Data1 ------ NC
  09 - Data2 ------ NC
  10 - Data3 ------ NC
  11 - Data4 ------ 10
  12 - Data5 ------ 11
  13 - Data6 ------ 12
  14 - Data7 ------ 13
  15 - +LCD ------- 5V
  16 - -LCD ------- GND
*/

//include LCD library
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

//Initialize an LCD object
/*Pins should be mentioned in this order:
  Reset
  Enable
  Data4
  Data5
  Data6
  Data7
*/
LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
int onTimePin = A0;
int onTime = 0;
int offTimePin = A1;
int offTime = 0;
int ledPin = 13;

void setup()
{

  pinMode(onTimePin, INPUT);
  pinMode(offTimePin, INPUT);

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  //Begin the LCD interface
  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  lcd.print("ON  TIME : ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("OFF TIME : ");

}

void loop()
{
  onTime = map(analogRead(onTimePin), 0, 1023, 1, 3);
  lcd.setCursor(11, 0);
  lcd.print(onTime);

  offTime = map(analogRead(offTimePin), 0, 1023, 1, 9);
  lcd.setCursor(11, 1);
  lcd.print(offTime);

  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(onTime * 1000);

  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(offTime * 1000);
}
```

The above code works. But there is a small problem:

When I turn the potentiometer wiper, there is a delay.

It's obvious because when the loop completes, the changed value of potentiometer is displayed. So, I decided to do the same thing using interrupts. But only digital pins have interrupts.

I would like to know the solution for using interrupts on analog input.

Comment: There's a delay because you're delaying.

Comment: I'd put the led blinking inside a timer(-interrupt). Or use the technique described in [blink without delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I know that there is a delay and I get the expected output. In short I want to have an led blinking as per the values given by potentiometer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Avoid `delay`](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvoidDelay).

Very simplistic alternative:

```
unsigned long lastLedToggleTime;
unsigned long currentLedToggleInterval;

void loop() {
  ...

  unsigned long now = millis();

  if ( (now - lastLedToggleTime) > currentLedToggleInterval) {
    lastLedToggleTime = now;
    // We need to toggle the LED now.
    if ( digitalRead( ledPin ) == LOW ) {
      // LED was LOW, so we set it HIGH and setup next toggling after onTime.
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      currentLedToggleInterval = (onTime * 1000);
    } else {
      // LED was HIGH, so we set it LOW and setup next toggling after offTime.
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      currentLedToggleInterval = (offTime * 1000);
    }
  } 
  ...
}
```

Notice that we're dealing with 32 bit *unsigned* integer values here, which is why this code will work even if/when `millis()` rolls over to 0. Specifically, not only will `now - lastLedToggleTime` always return a positive value (because it is cast into the unsigned data type), it will also return the *correct* value due to two's complement representation and modulo arithmetic base 2^32.

Example: Let's just look at an 8 bit value for simplicity:

Say, `lastLedToggleTime` was at the last tick of the 8 bit timer value, i.e. `lastLedToggleTime == 255`. In the next timer tick, `now` will overflow to `0`, so next we have `now` - `lastLedToggleTime` = 0 - 255 = -255. In [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), this value would need (at least) 9 bits to represent (binary: `1 0000 0001`), but because we only have 8 bits of storage, the sign bit (MSB) is just discarded resulting in `0000 0001` binary = 1. We can see that 1 is the correct value for the number of ticks to get from 255 to 0; it's exactly one tick.

Comment: Your solution will fail when `millis()` rolls over. Although this may not be a very serious issue, there is no reason to keep the bug, especially since it is very easy to avoid. See the [Blink Without Delay Arduino tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) for the proper way to write the code.

Comment: `millis()` ["will overflow (go back to zero), after approximately 50 days."](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Millis)

Comment: This is why I say “this may not be a very serious issue”. But yet, there is no valid reason to show buggy code in an answer, when it is just _so easy_ to avoid the bug. The pseudo-code in the page you link to is also correct.

Comment: @EdgarBonet You did notice that the OP has both variable and independent *on* and *off* times?

Comment: @EdgarBonet Since it seems to be really bugging you as it was, I edited your proposed solution in now.

Comment: Thank you. I have verified the code sample and it works fine.

Comment: @EdgarBonet It will fail with the Blink Without Delay Code as well. Once millis() rolls over the pin in the example given will never go HIGH again. It will stay low. You will never get a result again greater than *interval* once rolled over. You need the absolute value of the interval... *abs(interval)*

Comment: @FredHendricks, You don't understand the roll over. read https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12587/how-can-i-handle-the-millis-rollover

Comment: @FredHendricks Notice that we're dealing with *unsigned* 32 bit integers here which means we implicitly have modulo arithmetic. That's why `now - lastLedToggleTime` will always return the correct value, even when `lastLedToggleTime` is greater than `now` because `now` overflowed back to 0.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the bad solution for a simple problem. As Ignacio
Vazquez-Abrams puts it, the problem is you using `delay()`. The simplest
solution is to manage the timings with `millis()`. See the [Blink
Without Delay Arduino
tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay).