# How do I call functions sequentially without using the Delay function?

Tags: led, timers

I've been messing with the Adafruit Neopixel lib, and I'm trying to replace some of the delay functions with mills ( so that I don't block the serial port ). So far I have the following code;

```
void loop() {  
  currentMillis = millis();

  colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), 50); // Red
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 0), 50); // Green
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 255), 50); // Blue
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0, 255), 50); // White RGBW
}

void colorWipe(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= 200) {
    for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
      strip.show();
      //delay(wait);
      Serial.println("Light");
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
    }
   Serial.println("Done");
  }
}
```

The issue I'm running into ( and I do understand this is fundamental concept in Arduino programming ) is how to run sequential functions, like the ones in loop, while still not blocking the main loop. The way this currently functions, it runs through the first colorWhipe loop and then just keeps iterating.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want to run each `colorWipe` for 200 ms, one after another.

You need a state machine to timing each `colorWipe`, like this:

```
void loop()
{
    static int state = 0;
    static unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

    if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= 200) {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;

        switch(state) {
        case 0 :
            colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), 50); // Red
            state++;
            break;

        case 1 :
            colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 0), 50); // Green
            state++;
            break;

        case 2 :
            colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 255), 50); // Blue
            state++;
            break;

        case 3 :
            colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0, 255), 50); // White RGBW
            Serial.println("Done");
            state = 0;
        }
    }
}

void colorWipe(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait)
{
    for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
        strip.show();
        //delay(wait);
        Serial.println("Light");
    }
}
```

In each `loop` you will be waiting 200 ms before doing anything. When the times comes, you will enter the `if` with `state==0` and you will execute the first 'colorWipe'. After that, you *advance* the state by adding 1 to `state` variable.

Then you will be entering `loop` and doing nothing for another 200 ms. When that time pass, you will enter the `ìf` with state==1. Now the second `colorWipe` will be executed.

When the last colorWipe is executed, you set `state` to zero and begin again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the commented out delay in colorWipe should still happen then you need to nest the state machines:

```
void loop()
{
    static bool waiting=false;
    static int state = 0;
    static unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if(waiting){
        if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= 200){
            waiting = false;
        }
    }


    if(!waiting  && currentMillis - previousMillis >= 50) {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;

        switch(state) {
        case 0 :
            if(colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0))){ // Red
                state++;
                waiting = true;
            }
            break;

        case 1 :
            if(colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 0))){ // Green
                state++;
                waiting = true;
            }
            break;

        case 2 :
            if(colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 255))){ // Blue
                state++;
                waiting = true;
            }
            break;

        case 3 :
            if(colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0, 255))){ // White RGBW
                state++;
                state = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

int wipeState = 0;
bool colorWipe(uint32_t c)
{

    strip.setPixelColor(wipeState , c);
    strip.show();

    Serial.println("Light");
    wipeState++;
    if(wipeState == strip.numPixels()){
        wipeState = 0;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an OOP solution. (It seems a lot of Arduino programmers shy away from C++ classes, but I use them all the time).

Since you don't want to block `loop()`, you need to create a function that will set the pixel (if time has expired) and return immediately. I would create a class to encapsulate the pixel strip.

The way this works is the class has a `loop()` function that needs to be called every time in the main program's `loop()` function. The class's `loop()` will either return (almost) immediately or it will update the pixel. Which will also be very quick. This allows you to do other things in the main `loop()`.

Disclaimer: I just whipped this up, there may be bugs.

```c++
// A class to encapsulate the neo pixel strip.
class color_strip {
    protected:
    Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels;
    uint32_t last_ms;
    uint32_t color;
    uint32_t duration = 0;
    int current_pixel;
    bool first_time;

    public:
    // Constructor
    color_strip(int num_pixels, int pin) {
        strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(num_pixels, pin, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
    }

    // Call this from setup()
    void setup() {
       strip.begin();
    }

    // Call this to start a wipe
    // param duration_ms is how long the entire wipe should take
    void wipe(RGB color, uint32_t duration_ms) {
        // Calculate how long to light each pixel
        duration = duration_ms / strip.numPixels()
        // Initialize this data for loop()
        last_ms = millis();
        first_time = true;
        this->color = strip.Color(color.red, color.green, color.blue);
        current_pixel = 0;
    }

    void loop() {
        // Is there something to do? Only if duration != 0
        if (0 != duration) {
            // Time to change pixel?
            uint32_t current_ms = millis();
            if (current_ms - last_ms >= duration || first_time) {
                first_time = false;
                // Finished the entire wipe?
                if (current_pixel == strip.numPixels()) {
                    duration = 0;
                }
                else {
                    // Set the pixel
                    strip.setPixelColor(current_pixel++, color);
                    strip.show();
                    // Save
                    last_ms = ms;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Returns true if doing a wipe, else false
    bool working() {return duration != 0;}
};
```

Usage: you can create an array of colors. You then cycle through all these colors. If you want to add more colors, simply add to the array.

```c++
// Helper struct to store rgb
struct RGB {
    byte red, green, blue;
};
RGB all_colors[] = {
    {255, 0, 0},
    {0, 255, 0},
    {0, 0, 255},
    {0, 0, 0}
    // Add more colors here, if needed
};
// Need to keep track of the current color being displayed
byte current_color = 0;
const byte num_colors = sizeof(all_colors) / sizeof(all_colors[0]);

// Here's the actual object
// Change the parameters to whatever they need to be in your setup
color_strip strip(number_of_pixels, pin_number);

void setup()
    // Call the class setup function
    strip.setup();
}

void loop()
{
    // If the strip has completed its wipe, set it to next color
    if (!strip.working()) {
        current_color = (current_color + 1) % num_colors;
        strip.wipe(all_colors[current_color], 1000);
    }
    // Call the class loop(). It will return quickly so won't block
    // the rest of the program
    strip.loop();

    // Do other stuff here...    
}
```

Comment: Well, the OP have problems with a simple algorithm. I don't think using *classes* will be the best approach for him. Using C++ produces brain damage.

Comment: By adding duration to millis, you introduce the rollover problem.

Comment: @LookAlterno Not sure if that's a joke or not....Anyway, OP needs to be able to handle classes. `Adafruit_NeoPixel` is a C++ class.

Comment: @Jot Rollover should not be an issue with unsigned variables. See the answer here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12587/how-can-i-handle-the-millis-rollover

Comment: @JohnnyMopp. I use classes and I wrote them too. C++ i's like an enema, something you have to do, but not mean to be enjoyed.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp As far as I know, calculating a time in the future has the rollover problem. I mean this line "last_ms = millis() + duration;". Suppose duration is 10 and millis is 0xFFFFFFFA. Then last_ms will become 4. The next millis() - last_me will return 0xFFFFFFF6, which is larger than duration, but millis() has not even counted to the next millisecond.

Comment: @Jot Ok. I thought you were referring to the main loop. I just through that in there to force an update the first time. I've replaced it with a flag. Thanks.