# Atmega328P Prescaler to Microseconds

Tags: timing

For a bitbanging project I'm working on, I need to measure microseconds as accurately as possible. The function micros() won't work for me here because of the unpredictable times at which it might roll over. I have been using this project by Louis Frigon as an example:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140627135927/http://www.sigmaobjects.com/toyota/

In this document he sets his Atmega8's prescaler value:

```
// Timer 0 prescaler = 8 ( 1 count / us )
TCCR0 = _BV(CS01);
```

Do I understand that after these instructions, TCNT0 counts up by nearly precise microseconds?
If so, what math could I use to set my prescaler for measuring microseconds? The 328P has a higher clock speed, does that mean I won't be able to do this?

Comment: Note that [the rollover is not an issue](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12587). The limited resolution of `micros()` (4 µs) could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The 328P has a higher clock speed

The 328P will run at whatever speed you clock it, up to a maximum that
depends on the supply voltage. Most 328P-based Arduinos are clocked at
16 MHz though.

> what math could I use to set my prescaler for measuring microseconds?

You can't. You would have to set the prescaler to 16 if you want the
timer to count microseconds. You can set it to 8 or to 64, but there is
no intermediate setting in between.

Maybe you could leave the prescaler at 8 and count half-microseconds
instead?

---

**Edit**: On the 328P, Timer 0 has *two* control registers, named
`TCCR0A` and `TCCR0B`. To set it to normal counting mode at `F_CPU`/8,
you have to:

```c++
TCCR0A = 0;
TCCR0B = _BV(CS01);
```

If you are programming in plain C, the first line is not needed (but it
won't hurt either), as the initial value of `TCCR0A` is zero on reset.
If you are using the Arduino core library (and you write `setup()` and
`loop()` instead of `main()`), then you do need this first line, as the
Arduino core configures Timer 0 for PWM at 977 Hz. But note
that the Arduino core also uses Timer 0 for timekeeping
(`millis()`, `micros()` and `delay()`). Thus you may want to use another
timer.

You could switch to Timer 2 by replacing every “0” with a “2” on
the register and bit names of the two lines above. Then you would also
replace every occurrence of `TCNT0` in the code with `TCNT2`.

Comment: I've set my prescaler and I'm on my way. Thank you. I don't fully understand how it works, still, but I'm reading about it.