# i am having Strange issues when trying to read form gps serial connection

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, i2c, adafruit, serial-data

I have an Adafruit Ultimate GPS connected to a MEGA2560. I am trying to get the data from the buffer and do other data processing at the same time, however. when i allow other processing to be done the output becomes garbled such as below. the first out is correct and then becomes garbled and outputs now useful data.

16:34:54.466 -> $GPGGA,163453.155,,,,,0,00,,,M,,M,,*7F

16:34:57.111 -> $GPRMC,163453.155,V,,,,$GP$GPGGA,1$GPGGA,$GPGGA

```
    void loop()                  
    {

    GetTotalPressure();
      char c = GPS.read();
      Serial.print(c);
       if (GPS.newNMEAreceived()) {


        if (!GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA()))   // this also sets the newNMEAreceived() flag to false
          return;  // we can fail to parse a sentence in which case we should just wait for another
      }
      if (timer2 > millis())  timer2 = millis();


      if (millis() - timer2 > 1000) {
        timer2 = millis(); // reset the timer
    GPSScreenUpdate();
      SDcardSave();

      }
```

When GetTotalPressue is commented out The GPS serial output is correct when it is no the error above happens.

GetTotalPressure is below the sensor is connected to a I2C bus

```
void GetTotalPressure() {
  Totalpressure = ms5611.readPressure();
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Please, link to the GPS library you are using.

Comment: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_GPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reading the GPS often enough. The method
`Adafruit_GPS::read()` is documented in the [comments embedded in the
source code](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_GPS/blob/96625de7d35302294ee648af6a050332e0d30186/src/Adafruit_GPS.cpp#L352-L359):

> Read one character from the GPS device.
>
> Call very frequently and multiple times per opportunity or the buffer
>   may overflow if there are frequent NMEA sentences. An 82 character
>   NMEA sentence 10 times per second will require 820 calls per second,
>   and once a loop() may not be enough. Check for newNMEAreceived() after
>   at least every 10 calls, or you may miss some short sentences.
>
> returns: The character that we received, or 0 if nothing was available

Accessing the I2C bus makes `loop()` slower, slow enough that you get a
buffer overflow, as explained above. I suggest that, instead of reading
a single character per loop iteration, you read as many as are present
in the buffer:

```cpp
void loop()
{
    GetTotalPressure();

    // Empty the GPS port receive buffer.
    while (GPS.available()) {
        char c = GPS.read();
        Serial.print(c);
    }

    // Parse any newly received NMEA sentence.
    if (GPS.newNMEAreceived()) {  // clears the newNMEAreceived flag
        if (!GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA()))
            return;
    }

    // Display and log location every second.
    if (millis() - timer2 > 1000) {
        timer2 = millis(); // reset the timer
        GPSScreenUpdate();
        SDcardSave();
    }
}
```

As an aside, I removed the line

```cpp
if (timer2 > millis()) timer2 = millis();
```

which serves no useful purpose. If you are trying to detect `millis()`
overflows, [you are almost certainly doing something wrong](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12587/how-can-i-handle-the-millis-rollover).