# Millis() based timer program for 24x7 usage in Arduino

Tags: programming, timers

I have made an irrigation system using Arduino. Timer program is based on comparing the previous Millis() and current Millis(). I want to know the chance for error when the currentMillis() overflows and start from zero after 50 days, while the previous Millis() stored in the variable remains as a larger value.

Comment: What do you mean with "chance of error"? If you do it like in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example the overflow is no problem as long as the time difference between the previous `millis()` value and the current one stays below the ~50 days, since `millis()` just cannot count longer.

Comment: See [How can I handle the millis() rollover?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12587).

Comment: arduino timekeeping is not accurate if you do not use an RTC module .... it is ok for timing intervals, such as watering every 12 hours ... but it is unable to water at a specific time

Comment: this may be useful ... https://github.com/OpenSprinkler