# Why is sensitivity (threshold) parameter ignored

Tags: arduino-mega, c++, platformio, vscode

Analog pontentiometer connected to an Arduino. simplest possible setup.
The goal is to send a message over `Serial` whenever the value changes.

I do not want to spam the Serial connection to much, so the value has to change by at least `20` (sensitivty threshold) before a message Packet is sent.

However, in reality a message Packet is sent even if the value changed only by `1`. **Why is sensitivity parameter ignored?**

**edit:** After debugging I can see that it enters the first IF-statement in `read()`. The IF statement evaluates to `0` which is super weird. It shouldn't have entered that IF statement!

**MagicPot.h:**

```
#define MAGIC_POT_MAX_RAW_VALUE_10B     1023
#define MAGIC_POT_MAX_RAW_VALUE_12B     4095
#define MAX_RAW_VALUE_DEFAULT           (MAGIC_POT_MAX_RAW_VALUE_10B)

class MagicPot
{
    public:
        typedef void (*callback_fn)();
        MagicPot(uint8_t pin, uint16_t minRead = 0, uint16_t maxRead = MAX_RAW_VALUE_DEFAULT, uint16_t maxRawRead = MAX_RAW_VALUE_DEFAULT): pin(pin), minRead(minRead), maxRead(maxRead), maxRawRead(maxRawRead) {};
        void begin();
        bool read(uint8_t sensitivity = 5);
        uint16_t getValue();
        uint16_t getRawValue();
        uint8_t pin;

    private:
        uint16_t minRead;
        uint16_t maxRead;
        uint16_t maxRawRead;
        callback_fn onChangeCallback;
        uint16_t value;
        uint16_t rawValue;
};
```

**MagicPot.cpp:**

```
void MagicPot::begin()
{
    this->onChangeCallback = nullptr;
    this->value = 0;
    this->rawValue = 0;
    pinMode(this->pin, INPUT);
    this->read(0);
}

bool MagicPot::read(uint8_t sensitivity)
{
    this->rawValue = analogRead(this->pin);

    uint16_t value = map(this->rawValue, 0, this->maxRawRead, this->minRead, this->maxRead);

    if (abs(value - this->value) > sensitivity)
    {
        this->value = value;
        return true;
    }
    else if (value < sensitivity && this->value != this->minRead)
    {
        this->value = minRead;
        return true;
    }
    else if (value + sensitivity > maxRead && this->value != this->maxRead)
    {
        this->value = this->maxRead;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Arduino code:**

```
MagicPot analogPots[] = 
{
    MagicPot(A0),
}

void setup() {
  for (MagicPot& x : analogPots) //arr only contains 1 element
    x.begin();
}
void loop() {
  for (MagicPot& pot : analogPots) //arr only contains 1 element
  {
    if(true == pot.read(20))
      {
        CPPacket* analogPotChangedPacket = new CPPacket(HWEvent::Switch, pot.pin, pot.getValue());
        SendPacket( &myPacketSerial, analogPotChangedPacket);
        delete analogPotChangedPacket;
      }
  }

}
```

**Actual Output: (read from computer(conn via Serial))**

| Type | Error | Target | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Switch | NONE | 54 | 516 |
| Switch | NONE | 54 | 515 |
| Switch | NONE | 54 | 514 |
| Switch | NONE | 54 | 513 |

**Expected Output:**

| Type | Error | Target | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Switch | NONE | 54 | 516 |
| Switch | NONE | 54 | 496 |
| Switch | NONE | 54 | 456 |
| Switch | NONE | 54 | 436 |

Comment: you subtract two unsigned types so the result is stored in an unsigned temporary too. try `abs((int16_t) value - this->value)`

Comment: @Juraj: It should be either `abs((int16_t) (value - this->value))` or `abs((int16_t) value - (int16_t) this->value)`. Or, better yet, make everything signed. Otherwise, if only one term of the subtraction is signed, the unsigned type wins the “usual arithmetic conversions” game.

Comment: @EdgarBonet  Thank you, the weird behaviour was caused by uint16. I tested running the code (with **uint**) in VisualStudio and there it worked. Do you know why it worked in VS/Win11 but not in Arduino?  Is the c++ version different? Compiler?  And why didn't the compiler warn me? Ps, I am a complete beginner in c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this subtraction:

```cpp
value - this->value
```

Like in any arithmetic operation, the operands undergo [integral
promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion), then [usual arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/usual_arithmetic_conversions).
Oversimplifying a bit, “integral promotion” means that types smaller
than `int` get promoted to `int`, whereas “usual arithmetic conversions”
mean the smaller operand gets promoted to the type of the bigger one. If
both types have the same size, the unsigned one wins.

On the Arduino Mega, and `int` is 16 bits. Since the operands of the
subtraction are both `uint16_t`, the types are not changed by these
implicit conversions. The subtraction is performed with the `uint16_t`
type and wraps around modulo 2<sup>16</sup>. If you expect −1, you get
65535.

If you cast one of the operands to `int16_t`, then it will be implicitly
converted back to `uint16_t` by the usual arithmetic conversions, and
you get the same result.

On your PC, an `int` is 32 bits, thus both operands get implicitly
converted to `int` by integral promotion, and you get the expected
signed result.

The simple solution to your problem is to turn all your variables to
`int16_t`. I suggest you always use signed types by default, and revert
to unsigned types when you do need the wraparound semantics of the
arithmetic operations ([it is useful](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/12588/7508) sometimes).